# How do I separate URLs for different groups in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am developing a login screen using Django-allauth.
I would like to change the design of the login screen for Group A and Group B.
To do this, we would like to change the URL settings of the login screen for each.

Also, pages other than the login,
I want Group A to transition to

- https://xxxx/groupa/account/login/
- https://xxxx/groupa/toppage/
- https://xxxx/groupa/editpage/

I want group B to transition to

- https://xxxx/groupb/account/login/
- https://xxxx/groupb/toppage/
- https://xxxx/groupb/editpage/

Perhaps it would be better to separate the application for Group A and Group B, but I want to keep the source code common except for the login screen.

Below is the code I tried.

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = 'account/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

urls.py

```
path('<str:group>/account/', include('allauth.urls'), name="account_info"), 
path('<str:group>/', include('member.urls')),
```

I get an error when accessing
`https://xxxx/groupa/account/login/`

```
NoReverseMatch at /groupa/account/login/
Reverse for 'account_signup' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<group>[^/]+)/account/signup/\\Z']
```

Is there some middleware or something that forces the URL to change?

I am a beginner and very confused.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: Do you want to use the same backend code with both screens, with no change at all?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
For login, I am thinking of a different backend code.
For the others, I am thinking of using the same backend code.

Answer (score 0):

Try determine the group in the view logic, instead of in the url.

```
def foo_view(request):
    if request.user.groups.filter(name='groupa').exists():
        template = 'groupa_templates/foo.html'
    else:
        template = 'groupb_templates/foo.html'
    # some other view logic
    return render(request, template, context)
```

You can use the same url for both groups

-- Edited --

Suppose this is the view function

```py
def login_view(request, group):
    ..
    context = {'group': group}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Then in the template

```html
{% url 'allauth:account_sign' group %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
As you mentioned, we considered changing it in the View logic. However, we decided to forgo switching in the View logic because we do not know which group the user belongs to since it is the pre-login screen.
We thought it would be better to be able to change by URL, but we don't know how to return to the very first login screen on logout.
Also, I think it would be possible to have the login information in the session, but I am wondering what to do if the session is lost in the middle of the session.

Comment: I see. I mistook the Group you mentioned with an auth group. According to the error message, did you forget to supply the `group` parameter with `groupa` in your sign-up url tag in your login template?

Comment: That's true.I forget to supply the group parameter with groupa in your sign-up url tag in your login template.
But I do not know how to do it.
Also not sure how to keep adding <str:group> to all URLs

Comment: Just use the tag like `{% url 'allauth:account_signup' group %}`, where `group` is the name of the variable the url dispatcher send to your view function and you pass it to render context. I should edit my answer to make this clear.

Comment: I see.
If I want to do something like path('<str:group>/account/', include('allauth.urls'), name="account_info") 
 would I need to do {% url 'xxxx' group %} for all screen transitions?

Comment: That’s right. You need to do it all the time.

Comment: I knew it. Thank you very much for all the information.